# Use mod_rewrite to redirect to different pages depending on number of variables

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am currently using the mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

This works fine to make `/page` load `page.php?slug=page`.

However, I want to URL:

```
/cat/page
```

to load

```
page.php?slug=page
```

And the URL

```
/cat
```

to load the page

```
cat.php?slug=cat
```

Is this possible? I could do it on one page.php and use an if to determine which page it should be, however as the code for the category page and the page page is so different, I'd much rather keep them separate.

Thank you,

Sam

**Update:** More examples, as requested.

`/food/pizza` loads `page.php?slug=pizza`

`/food` loads `cat.php?slug=pizza`

`/animals/pigs` loads `page.php?slug=pigs`

`/animals` loads `cat.php?slug=animals`

Comment: Please describe more how should the redirect work... I don't see clean algorithm to implement. Give me more examples or describe the algorithm by yourself in pseudolanguage

Comment: @KamilŠrot I've tried to add more examples. Not sure if this is what you want, but I hope it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=cat.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ cat.php?slug=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=cat.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

I'm not sure about the names of parameters to `cat.php` and `page.php` as your examples are not consistent (sometimes it's `slug` and sometimes `cat`?) Anyhow it's minor problem.

Description: the `RewriteCond` make sure `page.php` and `cat.php` will not be rewritten. Then there are regular expressions matching one or two levels of virtual directories passing the request to correct PHP script.

EDIT: not. it's passing it to **really** the correct script :-)

Comment: Thank you, this works, although the cat.php and page.php are on the wrong rules. I swapped them and it works. Thanks! (And, it should always be slug and not cat - I mistyped, sorry!)